# AWS: how to get available memory in Windows

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2

On other machines, I have used the PowerShell cmdlet `Get-CimInstance` to get the total physical memory available:

```
(Get-CimInstance -class 'cim_physicalmemory') |
    Measure -Property capacity -Sum
```

But `Get-CimInstance -class 'cim_physicalmemory'` returns nothing on EC2.

Is there another CIM alternative to the [`CIM_PhysicalMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387968(v=vs.85).aspx) class for calculating the total amount of RAM available on the system?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the [`CIM_ComputerSystem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387219(v=vs.85).aspx) class contains the `TotalPhysicalMemory` property, which is approximately what I want. On a physical machine, the two don't have the same exact value, but they are close enough.